# Login with Facebook takes time to provide permission

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login

I want to include `Login with Facebook`. For that I believe I need to submit my website details to Facebook App Center.

My `App ID/App Key` & `App Secret` has been generated.

My `App Center Review` shows its pending review since past 4-5 days.

Is that so, does Facebook take time,to provide `oAuth` permission?? How long?

Or did I miss something?

```
  //Under App Details section on facebook
  App Detail Page Status: Live
  Your app detail page is now live and will appear in Search.

  App Center Listing Status: Unlisted
  Your app is not listed because it does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be listed in the App Center at this time. 
  Please refer to your app's Insights page to view your app's user rating and engagement metrics, and view our App Center guidelines for more information.
```

Comment: There isn't any approval process to use OAuth. Just for Open Graph actions.

Comment: @JanHančič Can you show me the right direction..?

Answer (score 0):

You are not require to submit the App Details, that is just for publishing your app in the App Center.

Simply follow the guide : [Facebook for websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)